# Отличия в способе запуска

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

Есть ли отличия в способе запуска:

```
uvicorn main:app
```

или

```
python main.py
```

При условии, что в `main.py` указано:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app.app, host='0.0.0.0', port='8080')
```

Следует уточнить, что я запускаю приложение на [fastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обратиться к исходному коду uvicorn.
Консольная команда `uvicorn` берется из настроек в setup.py, `секции entry_points`

Смотрим: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/setup.py#L84

`uvicorn=uvicorn.main:main` - это значит, что запускается функция `main` из модуля `uvicorn.main`.

Давайте посмотрим, что это за функция?

https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/main.py#L272

Она правит `sys.path` и с невероятной кучей аргументов, которые передаются через опции командной строки, запускает функцию `run`.
Отсюда можно решить, если ничего не перепутал, что разницы никакой.

Comment: Да, я ровно те же действия и проделал. Но на всякий случай решил уточнить у знающих людей, поскольку такой способ запуска мне кажется менее интуитивным.